# Paginate search results after combining sections in Craft 3

Tags: craft3, search

I have installed the Calendar plugin and I'd like to search across event entries from this plugin and from channel/section entries across the base Craft 3 site.

However, I am getting the usual Limit-Array error when trying to paginate the results.

Is there a method for paginating multiple search results in Craft 3? I haven't come across a way to do this in any current questions or Craft 3 Docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this is possible in Twig by default because you have two different Element types, thus you'll need to different instances of the ElementQuery to populate all models correctly. I think you'll need to create your own pagination. That being said `Element::find()->all()` will throw an error

> Cannot instantiate abstract class craft\base\Element

Thus you'll have to Query for your elements in your own

```
// get all possible element ids
$sectionId = X;
$query = (new Query())
    ->select('elements.id')
    ->from('{{%elements}}')
    ->leftJoin('{{%elements_sites}}', 'elements_sites.elementId = elements.id')
    ->leftJoin('{{%entries}}', 'entries.id = elements.id')
    ->where(new OrCondition([
        ['=', 'entries.sectionId', $sectionId], <-- your section Id
        ['is', 'entries.sectionId', null],
    ]))
    ->andWhere(new OrCondition([
        ['=', 'elements.type', \craft\elements\Entry::class],
        ['=', 'elements.type', YourCalenderClassComesHere],
    ]))
    ->andWhere(['elements_sites.siteId' => 1])
    ->limit(10)
    ->offset(0)
    ->column();

// populate entry by Id
foreach ($query as $elementId){
    $element = Craft::$app->getElements()->getElementById($elementId);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Robin. What a complete answer. I've yet to test myself with Craft Plugin work so I'll give writing one a go with this! Assuming you'd recommend this to be implemented in plugin form?

Comment: You need to implement it via plugin or module, these are the only ways to access custom php code. There are a few other checks you might want to include. The easiest is to run `Entry::find()->getRawSql()` to see all conditions Craft includes by default

Comment: This is great. Thanks for your help. I'll be sure to try and write my first plugin with this then! Cheers again. 